# How to use "fetchMore" with "useSuspenseQuery" from apollo graphQL in nextJS13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, next.js13

**the problem**

- useSuspenseQuery is experimental, but it follows the docs of useQuery, has the same helpers methods, including the "fetchMore"
- no matter what I do, **I keep receiving error 404**, with or without "updateQuery" inside the "fetchMore"
- I assume the URI is correct because when the page loads, it works like expected, "useSuspenseQuery" fetches the data correctly

**what I'm expecting**

- A pagination on relay-style cursor with graphQL
- Using "fetchMore" exposed with "useSuspenque" query to query additional pages.

**solution**

- the problem is envs just works in Server Side. to access this envs in client side, you need declare in the next.config.js.

```js
const Blog = () => {
  const { loading, error, data, client, fetchMore } = useSuspenseQuery(postsQuery, {
    variables: { first: 3 },
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network",
  });

  const { edges, pageInfo } = data.postsConnection;

  return (
    <Container>
      {<Posts posts={edges} />}
      <div>
        <button
          disabled={!pageInfo.hasNextPage}
          onClick={() =>
            fetchMore({
              variables: {
                first: 3,
                after: pageInfo.endCursor,
              },
              updateQuery: (previousResult, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
                const newEdges = fetchMoreResult.edges;
                const pageInfo = fetchMoreResult.pageInfo;

                return newEdges.length
                  ? {
                      postsConnection: {
                        __typename: previousResult.__typename,
                        edges: [...previousResult.edges, ...newEdges],
                        pageInfo,
                      },
                    }
                  : previousResult;
              },
            })
          }
        >
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: A 404 indicates that your server is getting a request that it cannot work with. Is the server uri correct and can it be reached from the browser?

Comment: @phry Yes, the uri is correct, at the page load, it loads correctly, but in this second iteration trigered by the button I have this error

Comment: If you use Nextjs, the first request is likely made from your server, while the second request is made from your browser - so it seems like your browser cannot reach your GraphQL endpoint correctly.
Can you take a look at your browser's network tab to verify if the url of the outgoing request is correct?

Comment: @phry you're right,
Request URL:
http://localhost:3000/graphql
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
404 Not Found

But I have no idea how I can change it, since it should work right out of the box, the idea of "fetchMore" is literally to fetch more using the same query and uri

Comment: It seems you need a graphql api that can also be accessed from your browser, not only from your server. In development, that can probably be localhost, but if it's on the web it needs to be hosted publically available.

Comment: @phry Thank you for your response, I figured out, the problem is envs just works in Server Side. to access this envs in client side, you need declare in the next.config.js.

your last commentary was valuable for me to understand the problem, thanks!